# CoreNLP Extracting Spans of Tokens

Tags: java, annotations, nlp, stanford-nlp

I would like to extract the spans of a tokenized `String` of text. Using Stanford's CoreNLP, I have:

```
Properties props;
props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");
this.pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

String answerText = "This is the answer";
ArrayList<IntPair> tokenSpans = new ArrayList<IntPair>();
// create an empty Annotation with just the given text
Annotation document = new Annotation(answerText);
// run all Annotators on this text
this.pipeline.annotate(document);

// Iterate over all of the sentences
List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
    // Iterate over all tokens in a sentence
    for (CoreLabel fullToken: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
        IntPair span = fullToken.get(SpanAnnotation.class);
        tokenSpans.add(span);
    }
}
```

However, all of the `IntPairs` are `null`. Do I need to add another `annotator` in the line:

```
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");
```

Desired Output:

```
(0,3), (5,6), (8,10), (12,17)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in using `SpanAnnotation`, which applies to `Trees`. The correct class for this query is `CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation` and `CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation`.

E.g. they can be used like so:

```
List<IntPair> spans = tokenSeq.stream()
    .map(token -> 
        new IntPair( 

  token.get(CoreAnnotations.CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation.class),

  token.get(CoreAnnotations.CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation.class)))
```

...excuse my indentation